# Why does iOS VoiceOver read April month incorrectly when the date is in medium format?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, nsdateformatter, voiceover

I have a `Date` object which is 04/04/2020.

**I am converting it into a string like:**

```
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none)
```

**so it is converted into:**

> Apr 4, 2020.

When iOS VoiceOver reads it, it reads the month as **A-P-R** instead of April.
For other months, it is read correctly. Mar is read March, Jan is read January.

**Is this an iOS bug or is there something I am missing?**

Comment: I am just going to use the long format instead of medium for it to sound correct, for now.

Comment: It looks like this is an iOS bug and can be reproduced on the Date & Time settings screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date extension:

```
extension Date {
   func monthName() -> String {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
      dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.currentLanguage)
      return dateFormatter.string(from: self).capitalized
   }
}
```

Then you will use this extension:

```
private func setupAccessibility(with date: Date) {
    self.accessibilityLabel = "\(date.day) \(date.monthName()) \(date.year)"
}
```

Comment: The big issue with this solution is that it doesn't take the user's locale into account.